# How to get cumulative sum SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

How to get cumulative sum SSRS report?

[image]

Comment: =RunningValue(Fields!Length.Value,Sum,"DataSet1")

Comment: did you already found answer or you have tried the expression mentioned in comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

=RunningValue(Fields!Length.Value,Sum,"DataSet1")